# Access MySQL database from Network Drive

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have an C# application that gets data from a mySQL workbench. The database is locally hosted on my local computer trough mysql workbench. At my work I have several Network drives which run 24h. Is there a way to store the mysql database in a folder on the network drive and access it from there ?.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: You can access it via IP

Comment: This link shows how to do it : https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/859917-create-database-network-drive, This link give the reasons why not to do it : https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/78378-possible-have-mysql-data-mapped-network-drive. Any reason why you don't install MySQL server on the network server?